# Не получается зайти на сайт https, браузер Awesomium

Tags: awesomium

Код на Vb.net для браузера Awesomium

Так входит по URL:

```
 WebControl1.Source = New Uri("https://ya.ru/")
```

А по этому URL нет:

```
 WebControl1.Source = New Uri("https://advego.ru")
```

Даже так не помогает:

'   Автоматически принимает HTTPS-сертификаты
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications